# How to display error message int the mern app in form

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-redux, mern, formik

I'm trying to display an error message when a user tries to login with an unregistered user, but I can't get that error message in the frontend (react) that I send from my backend (nodejs, express, MongoDB ).

I am using redux to handle the state of the react app.

Specifically, I somehow need to change the **login** function

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Box, Button, TextField, useMediaQuery, Typography, useTheme } from '@mui/material';
import { EditOutlined } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import * as yup from "yup";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setLogin } from 'state/authReducer';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';
import FlexBetween from 'components/FlexBetween';

const registerSchema = yup.object().shape({
    name: yup.string().required("Обязательное поле"),
    email: yup.string().email("Почта введена неправильно").required("Обязательное поле"),
    password: yup.string().required("Обязательное поле"),
    occupation: yup.string().required("Укажите вашу должность"),
    picture: yup.string().required("Выберите изображение для вашего профиля")
})

const loginSchema = yup.object().shape({
    email: yup.string().email("Почта введена неправильно").required("Обязательное поле"),
    password: yup.string().required("Обязательное поле"),
})

const initialValuesRegister = {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    occupation: ""
}

const initialValuesLogin = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
}

const Form = () => {
    const [pageType, setPageType] = useState("login");
    const { palette } = useTheme();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const isNonMobile = useMediaQuery("(min-width: 600px)");
    const isLogin = pageType === "login";
    const isRegister = pageType === "register";

    const register = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        for (let value in values) {
            formData.append(value, values[value])
        }
        formData.append("picturePath", values.picture.name);

        const savedUserResponse = await fetch(
            "http://localhost:5001/auth/register",
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: formData,
            }
        );
        const savedUser = await savedUserResponse.json();
        onSubmitProps.resetForm();

        if (savedUser) {
            setPageType("login");
        }
    }

    const login = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
        const loggedInResponse = await fetch(
            "http://localhost:5001/auth/login",
            {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
                body: JSON.stringify(values),
            }
        );
        const loggedIn = await loggedInResponse.json();
        onSubmitProps.resetForm();



        if (loggedIn) {
            dispatch(
                setLogin({
                    user: loggedIn,
                    token: loggedIn.token,
                })
            );
            navigate("/dashboard");
        } 
    };

    const handleFormSubmit = async(values, onSubmitProps) => {
        if (isLogin) {
            await login(values, onSubmitProps);
        }
        if (isRegister) {
            await register(values, onSubmitProps);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Formik
            onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
            initialValues={isLogin ? initialValuesLogin : initialValuesRegister}
            validationSchema={isLogin ? loginSchema : registerSchema}
        >
            {({
                values, 
                errors,
                touched,
                handleBlur,
                handleChange,
                handleSubmit,
                setFieldValue,
                resetForm,
            }) => (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Box
                        display="grid"
                        gap="10px"
                        gridTemplateColumns="repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr))"
                        sx={{
                            "& > div": {
                                gridColumn: isNonMobile ? undefined : "span 4"
                            },
                        }}
                    >
                        {isRegister && (
                            <>
                                <TextField 
                                    label="ФИО"
                                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    value={values.name}
                                    name="name"
                                    error={Boolean(touched.name) && Boolean(errors.name)}
                                    helperText={touched.name && errors.name}
                                    sx={{ gridColumn: "span 4" }}
                                />
                                <TextField 
                                    label="Должность"
                                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    value={values.occupation}
                                    name="occupation"
                                    error={Boolean(touched.occupation) && Boolean(errors.occupation)}
                                    helperText={touched.occupation && errors.occupation}
                                    sx={{ gridColumn: "span 4" }}
                                />
                                <Box
                                    gridColumn="span 4"
                                    border={`1px solid ${palette.divider}`}
                                    borderRadius="5px"
                                    p="1rem"
                                >
                                    <Dropzone
                                        acceptedFiles=".jpg,.jpeg,.png"
                                        multiple={false}
                                        onDrop={(acceptedFiles) => {
                                            setFieldValue("picture", acceptedFiles[0])
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        {({getRootProps, getInputProps}) => (
                                            <Box
                                                {...getRootProps()}
                                                border={`2px dashed ${palette.primary.main}`}
                                                p="1rem"
                                                sx={{ "&:hover": { cursor: "pointer" }}}
                                           >
                                                <input {...getInputProps()} />
                                                {!values.picture ? (
                                                    <p>Add Picture Here</p>
                                                ) : (
                                                    <FlexBetween>
                                                        <Typography>{values.picture.name}</Typography>
                                                        <EditOutlined />
                                                    </FlexBetween>
                                                )}
                                            </Box>
                                        )}
                                    </Dropzone>
                                </Box>
                            </>
                        )}
                        <TextField
                            autoComplete='new-password' 
                            placeholder="Логин"
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={values.email}
                            name="email"
                            error={Boolean(touched.email) && Boolean(errors.email)}
                            helperText={touched.email && errors.email}
                            sx={{ gridColumn: "span 4" }}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            autoComplete='new-password' 
                            placeholder="Пароль"
                            type="password"
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={values.password}
                            name="password"
                            error={Boolean(touched.password) && Boolean(errors.password)}
                            helperText={touched.password && errors.password}
                            sx={{ gridColumn: "span 4" }}
                        />
                    </Box>

                    {/* КНОПКИ */}
                    <Box>
                        <Button
                            fullWidth
                            type="submit"
                            sx={{
                                m: "1rem 0",
                                p: "1rem",
                                backgroundColor: palette.text.primary,
                                color: palette.background.alt,
                                "&:hover": {backgroundColor: palette.text.primary, boxShadow: "0 4px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 100px 80px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.02), 0 42px 33px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.024), 0 22px 18px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.028), 0 12px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.034), 0 7px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04), 0 3px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07)"}
                            }}
                        >
                            {isLogin ? "ВОЙТИ" : "ЗАРЕГЕСТРИРОВАТЬСЯ"}
                        </Button>
                        <Typography
                            onClick={() => {
                                setPageType(isLogin ? "register" : "login");
                                resetForm();
                            }}
                            sx={{
                                textDecoration: "underline",
                                color: palette.text.disabled,
                                "&:hover": {
                                    cursor: "pointer",
                                    color: palette.primary.main
                                },
                            }}
                        >
                            {isLogin 
                                ? "Нет аккаунта? Создайте его здесь." 
                                : "Уже есть аккаунт? Войдите здесь."}
                        </Typography>
                    </Box>
                </form>
            )}
        </Formik>
    )
}

export default Form;
```

My authReducer:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    user: null,
    token: null,
    mode: "dark", 
    userId: "63701cc1f03239c72c000180",
}

export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setLogin: (state, action) => {
            state.user = action.payload.user;
            state.token = action.payload.token;
        },
        setLogout: (state) => {
            state.user = null;
            state.token = null;
        },
        setMode: (state) => {
            state.mode = state.mode === 'light' ? "dark" : 'light';
        },
    }
})
export const { setLogin, setLogout, setClients, setMode } = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

Backend login code:

```
export const login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: "User does not exist! "});
        }

        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Invalid credentials! "});
    
        const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        delete user.password;
        res.status(200).json({ token, user });
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: e.message });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately fetch does not throw an error on 4xx responses, so you would need to build your own handler.

The promise returned by fetch returns into an Response object that has an “ok” property on it. So after fetch returns, check if loggedInResponse.ok is truthy, otherwise handle it as an error.

Comment: Can u help me with this handler?